# Difference between would/will. Are they interchangeable in certain contexts?

Tags: word-difference, word-in-context

> Words **wouldn't** be enough to describe my love for you.
>
> Words **won't** be enough to describe my love for you.

Are **Wouldn't/ Won't** interchangeable in the above construction?
What's the difference in their meaning if they're not?

Comment: These two words are never interchangeable without a difference in meaning.

Comment: For all practical purposes, both the above AND *Words **aren't** enough...* would all be interchangeable in most contexts. So go for the simpler present tense, [the same as nearly everyone else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=words+are+not+enough%2Cwords+will+not+be+enough%2Cwords+would+not+be+enough&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwords%20are%20not%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwords%20will%20not%20be%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwords%20would%20not%20be%20enough%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 3):

If I were to describe my love for you (hypothetical situation), words wouldn't be enough.

When I describe my love for you (future event), words won't be enough.